# How to lookup element by key using flatbuffer's Object API

Tags: flatbuffers

Is it possible to lookup elements by key with the object API just like it's possible in the non-object API with the "LookUpByKey" method?

I can't find any method that seems to do that.

Am I supposed to implement a binary search by myself on the vector?

Is the vector assumed to be already sorted?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use mini-reflection or full reflection for this task.

You can read more about reflection in the [docs](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_use_cpp.html) or see an example where it's used in their [testing code](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/blob/615616cb5549a34bdf288c04bc1b94bd7a65c396/tests/test.cpp#L914).

Here's a nice [tutorial by jorenjoestar](https://jorenjoestar.github.io/post/flatbuffers_reflection_data_driven_rendering/) from someone using reflection that I found helpful myself.

Also the vectors are not assumed to be sorted but you can pre-sort a vector and set the flatbuffer contents to that sorted vector.